# React js update state not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**My problem is**

I have a component where a button. You click on button then this vote count increment. This step going successfully. But problem is i have a video on that component when i click button that the video is playing from 0 second. I have use shouldcomponentupdate function then the increment count not updateing.

Comment: show some code, so that people can point out the mistake, Currently all answers would just be guesses

Answer (score 0):

Because when `setState` is called the component's lifecycle methods are called again. If you want to continue from the same place you'll need to save the current time in the video and continue playing from that time after the component renders

OR

Split the video component and the "like" component into separate components, react components render top to bottom not bottom to top. So if the change is only in the "like" component than the parent component will not reload, thus the video component will not reload

Finally,

`shouldComponentUpdate` returns either a `true` or `false` value to indicate whether the components render method should be called. You MUST return either true or false, nothing else. If you don't have a `shouldComponentUpdate` then the default value is always `true`

Comment: Can you come my system

Comment: If you’re appropriately separating your components then there is no need for shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: You can post a link to your source and I will look

Comment: Ok my comment is here [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LHEGlaQgwBtuYqbm8G6UP9VtHe65K6FQ)